# Trying to map an array of objects conditionally

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, redux

I'm trying to conditionally render some content on a screen. Basically, I have an array of 3 objects with some sub objects. This main object is stored in my reducer as the initial state (it is some dummy data). I have a Sidenav bar which has some links and I want to render some content to the right side of the side nav. I am using a custom sidenav so it may look a bit confusing, but my problem is I need to somehow map this array of 3 objects so I can render each object based on which link the user clicks. I will post the portion of the object that I am looking at (I actually posted a question about this earlier if you want to see the whole object). I'm a jr. dev so I'm sure this isn't something too complex.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import ReduxBurgerMenu from '../components/Menu';
import Chosen from '../components/Chosen';

class ExampleMenu extends Component {

  onClickDevices = (props) => {
    let devices = this.props.product;
    console.log(devices)
  }

  onClickLaptops = (props) => {
    let laptops = this.props.product[1];
    console.log(laptops)
  }

  onClickMobile = (props) => {
    let mobile = this.props.product[2];
    console.log(mobile)
  }

  onClickAny = (props) => {
    let devices = this.props.product;
    devices.map(obj => {
      return Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
        return (
          <tr>
            <td>{key}</td>
            <td>{obj[key]}</td>
          </tr>
        )
      })
    })
  }

    render () {
        let first = Object.keys(this.props.menu.products)[0];
        let second = Object.keys(this.props.menu.products)[1];

        return (
            <ReduxBurgerMenu isOpen={ this.props.isOpen }>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">{this.props.menu.title}</a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">{this.props.menu.description}</a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">{first}</a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">{second}</a>
                <button onClick={this.onClickDevices} id="Devices" className="menu-item" href="/">Devices</button>
                <button onClick={this.onClickAny} id="Laptop" className="menu-item" href="/laptops">{}</button>
                <button onClick={this.onClickMobile} id="Mobile" className="menu-item" href="/mobile">Mobile</button>
                <Chosen />
            </ReduxBurgerMenu>
        );
    }
}

// {JSON.stringify(this.props.products)}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    menu: state.reducer.menu,
    product: state.reducer.menu.products.product
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ExampleMenu);
```

---

and here is the object I am working with through the reducer

```
const initialState = {
  menu: {
        title: "Menu title",
        description: "Menu description",
        products: {
          title: "Products title",
          description: "Product description",
          product: [
            {
              device: {
                title: "Device title",
                description: "Device description",
                types: [
                  {
                    name: "Modem",
                    title: "Modem title",
                    description: "Modem description"
                  },
                  {
                    name: "charger",
                    title: "charger title",
                    description: "charger description"
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              laptop: {
                title: "Laptop title",
                description: "Laptop description",
                types: [
                  {
                    name: "Apple",
                    title: "Apple title",
                    description: "Apple description"
                  },
                  {
                    name: "Lenevo",
                    title: "Lenevo title",
                    description: "Lenevo description"
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              mobile: {
                title: "Mobile title",
                description: "Mobile description",
                types: [
                  {
                    name: "Samsung",
                    title: "Samsung title",
                    description: "Samsung description"
                  },
                  {
                    name: "Nokia",
                    title: "Nokia title",
                    description: "Nokia description"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
};
```

The product array with the 3 objects is what I was referring to. I also have some random functions just to see if I was getting the data or not with console.logs but ideally I want to use that onClickAny function to render either of the three objects on the right side (maybe in a list) based on whether someone clicked the devices, mobile, or laptop buttons. Please, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a state such as deviceType and change it to `laptop` when laptop is clicked.
And render it like

```
{ this.state.deviceType === 'mobile' && <div>Render this</div>}
{ this.state.deviceType === 'web' && <div>Render this thing</div>}
```

Does that make sense?

Let's start with an easy example:

```
onClickDevices = (props) => {
    let devices = this.props.product[0];
    let types = devices.types;
    return types.map((type) => {
       return (
         <tr>
            <td>{type.name}</td>
            <td>{type.title}</td>
            <td>{type.description</td>
         </tr> ) }

  }
```

Are you trying to do something like the above?

Comment: Hello, thank you for the comment. I have to be honest it kind of does but not really. The problem is in the product array, the names of the objects are different. And there are a bunch of sub objects/arrays which is why I'm confused. I just need help mapping the products array into an unordered list or something like that

Comment: Let's try to understand your problem better. Let's go with the mobile devices.

Comment: Yes exactly. I think something like that. Is there a way to  do this with all 3 objects? Instead of the [0]? And also, can I include this in the same file because that file is mainly for the sidebar. I could create a different component and then import that in my App.js?

Answer (score 0):

Make `ExampleMenu` as parentComponent to `RightSideOfTheNav` component (this is where you want to display your device info) or you can use your `Chosen` component

Add state to your `ExampleMenu` component

```
state = {
    requiredDevice: {}
}
```

Update your button in your JSX

```
<button onClick={() => this.onClickAny('device')} id="Devices" className="menu-item" href="/">Devices</button>
<button onClick={() => this.onClickAny('laptop')} id="Laptop" className="menu-item" href="/laptops">Laptop</button>
<button onClick={() => this.onClickAny('mobile')} id="Mobile" className="menu-item" href="/mobile">Mobile</button>
```

Here we are passing arguments to `this.onClickAny('devices')` statically.

Update your `onClickAny` method

```
onClickAny = (productType) => {
    let devices = this.props.product;
    var requiredDevice = devices.find(itemDevice => itemDevice.hasOwnProperty(productType))[productType]
    // if 'device' is passed as 'productType' 
    // var requiredDevice = devices.find(itemDevice => itemDevice.hasOwnProperty('device'))['device']
    // it returns
     // {
     //     title: "Device title",
     //     description: "Device description",
     //     types: [
     //              {
     //                name: "Modem",
     //                title: "Modem title",
     //                description: "Modem description"
     //              },
     //              {
     //                name: "charger",
     //                title: "charger title",
     //                description: "charger description"
     //              }
     //            ]
     // }
    this.setState({
        requiredDevice
    })
  }
```

Add in your JSX  in your `render()`

```
{ (Object.keys(this.state.requiredDevice).length > 0) && <RightSideOfTheNav device={this.state.requiredDevice} /> }
```

or maybe in your case it is `Chosen` component so

```
{ (Object.keys(this.state.requiredDevice).length > 0) && <Chosen device={this.state.requiredDevice} /> }
```

And Use `device` as `props` in your `Chosen` or `RightSideOfTheNav` component

Hope this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to store the selected category(`device`, `laptop` or `mobile`) in your component's state :

```
this.state = {
    selection: 'device'
}
```

Now give your button's a function pre-configured with the category they represent :

```
<button onClick={this.changeSlection('device')} id="Devices" className="menu-item" >Devices</button>
<button onClick={this.changeSlection('laptop')} id="Laptop" className="menu-item" >Laptop</button>
 <button onClick={this.changeSlection('mobile')} id="Mobile" className="menu-item" >Mobile</button>
```

And now, the new function to set your state depending on which one got clicked :

```
changeSlection = selection => ev => {
    this.setState({ selection })
}
```

To get the data you want, use the find function to know what object contains the selected key :

```
const selectedProduct = product.find(p => p[selection])[selection]
```

Fully functional example :

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            selection: 'device',
            product: [
                {
                    device: {
                        title: "Device title",
                        description: "Device description",
                        types: [
                            {
                                name: "Modem",
                                title: "Modem title",
                                description: "Modem description"
                            },
                            {
                                name: "charger",
                                title: "charger title",
                                description: "charger description"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    laptop: {
                        title: "Laptop title",
                        description: "Laptop description",
                        types: [
                            {
                                name: "Apple",
                                title: "Apple title",
                                description: "Apple description"
                            },
                            {
                                name: "Lenevo",
                                title: "Lenevo title",
                                description: "Lenevo description"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    mobile: {
                        title: "Mobile title",
                        description: "Mobile description",
                        types: [
                            {
                                name: "Samsung",
                                title: "Samsung title",
                                description: "Samsung description"
                            },
                            {
                                name: "Nokia",
                                title: "Nokia title",
                                description: "Nokia description"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }

    changeSlection = selection => ev => {
        this.setState({ selection })
    }

    render() {
        const { product, selection } = this.state
        const selectedProduct = product.find(p => p[selection])[selection]

        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.changeSlection('device')} id="Devices" className="menu-item" >Devices</button>
                <button onClick={this.changeSlection('laptop')} id="Laptop" className="menu-item" >Laptop</button>
                <button onClick={this.changeSlection('mobile')} id="Mobile" className="menu-item" >Mobile</button>
                <h5>{selectedProduct.title}</h5>
                <p>{selectedProduct.description}</p>
                {/* <MyComponent data={selectedProduct}/> */}
            </div>
        )
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'/>
```